# Number equations according to part

Tags: lyx

How can I number the displayed equations according to the part they are within?
E.g., in part 1 the formulas shall be numbered like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,.. Then in part 2 they shall be 2.1, 2.2, 2.3,.. 
I've googled a lot and apparently in https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/EquationNumbering#toc5 it is explained but all I get is numbering according to section: E.g. in part 1, chapter 4 the formulas are displayed as 4.1, 4.2,..

`\numberwithin{equation}{part}` does not work.
Thanks a lot in advance!

edit: My preamble is:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} 

\usepackage{diagbox}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{35pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{ colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!25!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} 

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{brightgray}{RGB}{245,245,245}
\numberwithin{equation}{part}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thepart.\thechapter.\arabic{equation}} 
\renewcommand*\thepart{\arabic{part}}

\renewcommand\[{\begin{equation}}
\renewcommand\]{\end{equation}}
```

and I have turned on `amsmath` in Document/Settings/Math Options

The document class is "Article (Standard Class)"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Can you please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess your document class etc and this makes it difficult to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Including a MWE that shows that `\numberwithin{equation}{part} ` does not do what you want would be sufficient.

Comment: Your preamble is not a valid MWE. You should include only what is necessary to reproduce your issue. Also you're missing the `\documentclass` and a small actual document (enclosed by `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) in which the issue is demonstrated.

Comment: Also you're using `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` which would result in resetting every section, not every part. It should be `\numberwithin{equation}{part}` if you want the equation counter to be reset by `\part`.

Comment: Probably dumb question: How do create this document in lyx? Shall I make an screenshot?

Comment: @Ben not a dumb question. You can export a .tex file in LyX by doing File > Export > LaTeX (pdflatex). Also note that you can post a minimal example .lyx file as explained here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try update the `\theequation`:

```
\numberwithin{equation}{part}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thepart\arabic{equation}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work almost. Only disadvantage is that the numbering is shown as following: I1, I2,..    is it maybe due to my font? Or why is that?

Comment: Ah, likely because the parts are already numbered as Part I, Part II, and so on. Any idea how to change this (in the formula numbering)?

Comment: Or if you want part number be arabic `\renewcommand*\thepart{\arabic{part}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you even know how to take care of chapters and sections in parallel? In part 1, chapter 2, section 3, is it possible to make the formula look like (1.2.3)?

Comment: Just update the `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thepart\thechapter\arabic{equation}}` etc.

Comment: \renewcommand*\thepart{\arabic{part}\arabic{chapter}} ends in 12.3 instead of in 1.2.3.

Comment: \renewcommand*\thepart\thechapter{\arabic{part} doesn't even work. Can you please advice?

Comment: Please, check what zou are updating. If zou update equation number zou need to update `\theequation` - `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thepart.\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}`

Comment: Thank you, how do I adjust this in your second command "\renewcommand*\thepart{\arabic{part}}"? I tried so much, I can't figure it out.

Comment: You don't need to adjust it, `\renewcommand*\thepart{\arabic{part}}` - is only for changing part numbering from roman to arabic numbers.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for hinting out but it's not working. Can you please have a look at my question?

Comment: this would be better as `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{part}.\arabic{equation}}`, assuming that the part number should be shown as an arabic numberal.

Comment: Thanks, this only takes into account the part. Within the part it just counts the number. For example, in Part 1, Chapter 2, Section 3 it is then 1.14.